# What is the Web Service Endpoint for the 'Close Financial Periods' screen (AP506000)?

Tags: acumatica

What is the Web Service Endpoint for the 'Close Financial Periods' screen (AP506000)?   I can't seem to find it (or anything similar) in the list of endpoints.  I need to select the oldest open period from the list of periods displayed on that screen.

Also - what's the best way to determine the name of the endpoint for a given screen, other than just looking for a similar name as the screen itself in the list of endpoints?

Thanks...

Comment: If you have access to the database. You can query EntityDescription table. Which you'll also find out that there's no endpoint for AP506000 unfortunately. Probably because its a processing screen.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks.  ;D

Comment: As a followup - where's the best place in Acumatica to get the current period?  As an old  Dynamics programmer, I used to use their CurrPerNbr - but Acumatica doesn't have anything like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the oldest open period, I would create a generic inquiry for the PX.Objects.GL.FinPeriods.MasterFinPeriod table. You can see ClosedInAP, ClosedInAr, etc. From there, you could make a filter to show only open periods, sorted ascending. Once you have it worked out, you could expose it to odata, or even extend your web service endpoint to get the data out.

Here is an example of periods that are not closed in AP, but closed in AR (and unclosed).

[image]